# Are there any results associated with $\int_{0}^{n} f(x)f(x+1) \cdots f(x+n) \,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I recently found a YouTube video that solves the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)\ln(x+1) \,dx$

This made me curious if we could generalize the integral and if there are any results or bounds associated with it.

Is $\int_{0}^{n} f(x)f(x+1) \cdots f(x+n) \,dx$ guaranteed to have a closed-form solution, if we assume that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?

This is my first post so my apologies if there's something wrong with my post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I've edited my question above.

Comment: This looks a lot like [convolution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html) but I cannot say for sure whether that link is entirely relevant or helpful.